# Removing a row from CSV file with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, row

I need guidance in how to remove rows having specific values in a column for each row.

For instance, column A has 50 rows and it has value 0 at different places.

I want to remove whole row that has value 0 for column A in a CSV file.

Following is the dataset from which I need to remove rows.

Row1: 1,95,90
Row2: 1,85,76
Row3: 0,100,71
Row4: 0,100,24
Row5: 1,100,76

I have tried `.drop` command in pandas but its not working.

Here is the code I have developed.

[image]

Comment: It's just indexing in pandas:
`df[df[column]!=0]`

Comment: Sorry @thomask didn't see your comment here before I answered!

Comment: Dear Thomask, thank you for your kind guidance. But I'm encountered with the same issue as this command is not working for me. I gave the header 'A1' to the first column while index is put false and then I used this command i.e. 
df = df[df["A1"] != "0"]
print(df)
But it is giving me following error. Any idea please..

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'A1'

Answer (score 1):

So start by loading the file in pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv")
```

Then subset where that condition is not found, i.e. df where df column A does not equal 0:

```
df = df[df["A"] != 0]
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your kind reply and the guidance. i think I'm close enough but then I encountered with another error may be due to any small issue that I couldn't see. I put header named 'A1' for the first column and then used this command: 
df = df[df["A1"] != "0"]
print (df)
But it is not working and showing error named KeyError: 'A1'
Can you please help in this regard?

Comment: Could you please provide the code? It sounds like it column name hasn't been assigned properly!

Comment: Yeah sure. Following is the code:
>>>df = pd.read_csv("output_file.csv")
>>>df.to_csv("output_file.csv", header = ["A1", "A", "B", "C", "D"], index = False)

>>>new_df = df.drop(df.index[df["A1"] != 0])

>>>print (new_df)

Comment: I believe it's because you're saving the CSV file, not changing as it is stored in memory. So you're trying to drop the column A1 of the variable df, but A1 doesn't exist in the variable df because you haven't reread it back. Try adding the line df = pd.read_csv("output_file.csv") before the new_df =... line

Comment: I have done it in the same way. In the first line of the post, I just put the picture of the code if you can please review. And if you have time to kindly guide it would be helpful to request your email id to share the further details of the code. Thanks

Comment: Yep so as I said previously you have not reread the csv file you've just saved ("output_file.csv"). Please add the line pd.read("output_file.csv") AFTER you have saved it. Also I'm not sure you need to be saving it here as you are continuing to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drop function with inplace=True which makes the changes on df itself;

```
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hello Kubra, thank you for your kind reply and guidance. I tried this command but it is removing all the rows. What is need is to remove whole rows with values equal to 0 in the first column. Can you kind help how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

If using [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools), then:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

rows = (
    Table.from_csv("tmp.csv", header=True)
    .filter(c.col("A") != "0")
    .into_csv("tmp-updated.csv")
)
```

Tables help - https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables.html